# Using np.where() + .iloc[] gets wrong result. Reason might be iloc[] no longer supports tuple format of index

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I wrote these codes where `np.where()` and `.iloc[]` is used to change `NaN`s to be `"missing"` in the dataframe. However, the result is wrong and the reason might be that `.iloc[]` recognized tuple index unsmartly.

Could anybody offer me some guidance to fix it or alternative methods aside from `fillna()`? Because the real case I want to solve is get indexes by applying conditions on `df1` and use the indexes to change values in `df2`, so `fillna()` might be unhelpful in my case.

```
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Mark'],
    'Age': [25, 31, np.nan, 28, 35],
    'Salary': [50000, np.nan, 70000, np.nan, 90000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
    Name   Age   Salary
0   John  25.0  50000.0
1  Alice  31.0      NaN
2    Bob   NaN  70000.0
3   Jane  28.0      NaN
4   Mark  35.0  90000.0
```

```
# Use np.where and .iloc to replace missing values with a specified value
value_to_replace = "missing"
missing_mask = np.where(df.isna())  # Create a boolean mask for missing values
df.iloc[missing_mask]= value_to_replace  # Use np.where for replacement
df
```

```
    Name      Age   Salary
0   John     25.0  50000.0
1  Alice  missing  missing
2    Bob  missing  missing
3   Jane  missing  missing
4   Mark     35.0  90000.0
```

The expected result should be:

```
    Name      Age   Salary  
0   John     25.0  50000.0  
1  Alice     31.0  missing  
2    Bob  missing  70000.0 
3   Jane     28.0  missing  
4   Mark     35.0  90000.0
```

Comment: Don't post your code and/or data as an image. No one can copy-paste and run it.

Comment: I just editted it! Could you please have another look? Thx!

Comment: Why do you want to replace the NaNs with "missing"? The column is probably currently of type `float`, but replacing it with "missing" will make it type `object`, which is less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would do this because you will change your `float` values to the `object` type, but it can be done. I would do the replacement using the [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method. This replaces values *where* a condition evaluates to `False`. Since we want to replace values that are `NaN`, we can use `isna` to find the `NaN`s and apply the logical NOT to make it `False` where the value is `NaN`. Alternatively, @[Timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus) pointed out that you can use `notna`, which does the same thing as the NOTed `isna`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Mark'],
    'Age': [25, 31, np.nan, 28, 35],
    'Salary': [50000, np.nan, 70000, np.nan, 90000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.where(~df.isna(), "missing")
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```py
    Name      Age   Salary
0   John     25.0  50000.0
1  Alice     31.0  missing
2    Bob  missing  70000.0
3   Jane     28.0  missing
4   Mark     35.0  90000.0
Name      object
Age       object
Salary    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Instead of `~df.isna()` you could use `df.notna()`.

Comment: @Timus Thanks, I probably should have checked for a function that does that.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this, and works fine for me :

```
import numpy as np

# Create the DataFrame
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Mark'],
        'Age': [25, 31, np.nan, 28, 35],
        'Salary': [50000, np.nan, 70000, np.nan, 90000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Specify the value to replace NAs
value_to_replace = "missing"

# Find the indices where values are missing
missing_mask = np.where(df.isna())

# Unpack the tuple of indices and replace missing values
df.iloc[*missing_mask] = value_to_replace

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: I ran your codes but my result is not correct

Comment: `Name      Age   Salary`

`0   John       25    50000`

`1  Alice  missing  missing`
`2    Bob  missing  missing`
`3   Jane  missing  missing`
`4   Mark       35    90000`

Comment: But isn't `df.iloc[*missing_mask]`  a syntax error?

Comment: yeah I deleted the * and ran again. Still wrong result for my